# 400 Bad Request : "Your request couldn't be completed" - ucwa batch request with postman

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa, batching

I sendes this batch request with postman:

```
POST /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/105177669305/batch HTTP/1.1
Host: lync.myDomain.com
Accept: multipart/batching
Content-Type: multipart/batching;boundary=6555373f-c163-b72d-5c00-c3cc6cb9cd52
Authorization: Bearer cwt=AAEBHAEFAAAAAAAFFQAAAJFDb5_gw6wKmbRiI5oNABENAxu_zcjj9Rt7KWK3RkJSKCAvAPgyCThFvNa0lFTBPm5usuFxhbNo5VqemqSOoI-qWc_fihdoYI4G_bjjSS1AgNENAxu_zcjj9Rt7KWK3RkJSI
X-Requested-With: xmlhttprequest
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 57195c61-6b6f-0db9-5760-0af268fe7d55

--6555373f-c163-b72d-5c00-c3cc6cb9cd52
Content-Type:application/http;msgtype=request
GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/10513269305/people/contacts HTTP/1.1
Host:lync.myDomain.com
Accept:application/json

--6555373f-c163-b72d-5c00-c3cc6cb9cd52
Content-Type:application/http;msgtype=request
GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/10513269305/me/presence HTTP/1.1
Host:lync.myDomain.com
Accept:application/json

--6555373f-c163-b72d-5c00-c3cc6cb9cd52--
```

and got response status "400 Bad Request" with "Your request couldn't be completed." message. Did i missed some headers? If you know any reason why i get this error, please, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

From w3.org

HTTP Code 400 Bad Request means;

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

Check your request syntax. What kind of request format does your server expect? Would you be able to check server logs?

Answer (score 0):

[Lines need to end with Windows style line endings (\r\n), and should follow the format which is not even mentioned in the documentation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2aca214f-f8d9-4e39-acb7-39cb46c0b226/400-bad-request-your-request-couldnt-be-completed-ucwa-batch-request-with-postman?forum=ucwebapi)

The following code is converted from batch.js in the UCWA samples, https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs/blob/master/Skype/UCWA/samples/scripts/Batch.js

And the request limit in Batch is 100.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    String boundary = "77f2569d-c005-442b-b856-782305305e5f";

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        parts.add(createDataPart(boundary));
    }

    String data = parts.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n"));
    data += "\r\n\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";

    try {
        HttpResponse<String> response =
            Unirest.post("https://lyncweb.example.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/10820256145/batch")
            .header("authorization", "Bearer cwt=CCCCHAEFAAAAAAAFFQAAANz03DsuQ6xAB-U7K3yFAACBEBUTVWulRKhftCre06OKSveCAgghgyBAJ_THbZjk1M3ICsm1apTszG7HcKGll6HUDlc4i_fEEoYIU0vz-ojC1QgNEBDrIobFox9WpyA_EhuC5Mk")
            .header("content-type", "multipart/batching;boundary=" + boundary)
            .header("accept", "multipart/batching")
            .body(data)
            .asString();

        System.out.println("Response1 \r" + response.getBody());

    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

String createDataPart(String boundary) {
    String dataPart = "\r\n--" + boundary;
    dataPart += "\r\nContent-Type: application/http; msgtype=request\r\n";
    dataPart += "\r\n" + "GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/10820256145/people/test.user@example.com/presence HTTP/1.1";
    dataPart += "\r\n" + "Host: " + "lyncweb.example.com";
    dataPart += "\r\n" + "Accept: " + "application/json";

    //if (part.Data) {
    //    dataPart += "\r\n" + "Data: " + JSON.stringify(part.Data);
    //}
    dataPart += "\r\n";
    return dataPart;
}
```